# How to create a button that creates an article with a specific tag?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I'm administrating a public site and there's some other guys who add content, too. We have a page with articles with a certain tag (let's call it `theTag`) which has an address like `the-site.com/taxonomy/term/41`. Now, since other users are not advanced ones (and for general convenience) I'd like to create a button which:

1. adds an article (opens the `the-site.com/node/add/article` or the corresponding overlay) with pre-set `theTag`
2. also I'd like the "is shown on the main page" flag (not sure about the exact name, it's "Помещено на главную страницу" in Russian) unset, so that the article is show only on the `the-site.com/taxonomy/term/41` page, not on the main one
3. the button should obviously be shown only to those who can edit

How to implement that? It sounds like a common feature, but googling didn't help. Since I'm totally new to Drupal internals, I'd appreciate any partial suggestions if you think I'm asking for too much.

PS may be there's some params that I can use in the `the-site.com/node/add/article` url (like, say, `the-site.com/node/add/article?tag=theTag`) so that the corresponding tag is pre-set in the new article form?

Comment: is your tag static or dynamic? I mean each time you want use specified tag name or always use one?

Comment: @zhilevan just the same tag each time, so static

Comment: do you prefer pass term name  or term id?
can you tell me your  content type name  and your tag field machine name ( I can guest they are article and field_tags) ?

Comment: @zhilevan nice specification. Since I'm not going to create many of such buttons anyway (just one for now), I think both will do, but term id sounds a bit better since renaming the term wouldn't break the code. Content type name is definitely article; not totally sure about the tag field machine name, but the input's DOM is `<input type="text" id="edit-field-tags-und" name="field_tags[und]" value="" size="60" maxlength="1024" class="form-text form-autocomplete" autocomplete="OFF" aria-autocomplete="list">` which suggests you're right.

Comment: where do you want put this button?
in drupal we have  link to create url as example in `content > add content > article `
would like to have a link for it , as exmaple  `content > add content > Помещено на главную страницу` ?

Comment: @zhilevan well, I'd like to add the button to a custom sidebar block, but adding to the `the-site.com/node/add` menu (which is usually shown via an overlay `the-site.com/smth#overlay=node/add`) would be an ok solution. Note that I'd like to *avoid* publishing the created article to the main page (which, by the way, is set via unchecking the `<input type="checkbox" id="edit-promote" name="promote" value="1" checked="checked" class="form-checkbox">` checkbox). In blocks, custom PHP is allowed and I'd appreciate using it (because I'll learn something about the core methods).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the [Prepopulate](https://www.drupal.org/project/prepopulate) module does exactly what you want.

EDIT:
From the module's page:

The Prepopulate module allows fields in most forms to be pre-populated from the $_REQUEST variable.

For example, the following URL,

```
http://www.example.com/node/add/blog?edit[title]=this is the title
```

will automatically fill the Title field on a new blog post with the words "this is the title". Any field can be prepopulated this way, including taxonomy and CCK fields. You can prepopulate more than one field at a time as well. Prepopulate is excellent for creating bookmarklets. For examples on usage for all of these cases, please read the USAGE.txt file that comes with the module or you can read the online handbook page.

Comment: Hi, thanks. The plugin looks useful, but I failed to set a tag with it. The DOM of the tags input is the following: https://jsfiddle.net/ge8sLux9/ . I've tried `the-site.com/node/add/article?edit[field_tags][und]=test`, `?edit[field_tags[und]]=test` and various others like `?edit[tags]=test`, `?edit[tags][0]=test` etc, but without success (although `?edit[title]=test` worked for me). I also failed to set the "to the main page" checkbox (`name="promote"`, I tried `edit[promote]=false` and `edit[promote]=0`).

Comment: The documentation of the module doesn't say what to do with hidden *and* disabled inputs, but I guess you can try any of the combinations given in the documentation:
https://www.drupal.org/node/228167